# How to align divs according to lg and/or md type using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to align divs according to md and/or lg type of devices as shown in attached image..

With the code I have written.. it is pushing col 9 div below col 3 div..

Please help me to resolve this problem..

html I am using is...

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-9">
```

`col 1`

`<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-lg-push-9">`
`col 3`
`</div>`
`<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">`
`col 2`
`</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work for you. Use "**pull-right**" class instead of the push class you have. This should do the trick.

This a **lg and md** example as you requested:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-9">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

This is a **lg, md, sm** if you want to add extra space to the side in smaller screen sizes.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-9 col-sm-8">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 pull-right">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

See an example here: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/abbomuren/qv7a1ado/)

Regards!

Comment: You welcome. You may like to take a look at these links:

Layout modeler for bootstrap:
http://www.layoutit.com/build

Side bar plugin for bootstrap:
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/